# Chrome.storage.local.get returning undefined in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I'm trying to use chrome.storage.local to save an object with info that I've gathered through an extension.

Here is the .set, when I console.log the result, it's working properly.

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'myKeyName': JSON.stringify(myObject)}, function() {

     chrome.storage.local.get('myKeyName', function (result) {
          console.log(result);
     });
});
```

In my react application, I then call the chrome.storage.local.get (same as above), and it's returning: "Cannot read property local of undefined". Even though I have added: /* global chrome */ at the top of the react file.

Here is the react function that isn't working properly and accessing the chrome.storage.local:

```
checkImportReady = (e) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (chrome.storage.local.get('myKeyName') === null) {
            this.setState({
                readyToImport: false
            });

            reject('Import Not Ready');
            console.log('Import Not Ready');
            
        } else if (chrome.storage.local.get('myKeyName') !== null) {

            this.setState({
                readyToImport: true
            });

            resolve('Import Ready');
            console.log('Import Ready');

            let returnedSavedData;
            chrome.storage.local.get('myKeyName', function (result) {
                returnedSavedData = result;
                //returnedSavedData = JSON.parse(returnedSavedData);
                console.log(returnedSavedData);
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                readyToImport: false
            });

            reject('Import Not Ready');
            console.log('Import Not Ready');
        }
    })
```

Edit: I'm trying to save information in a chrome extension. And then when the user navigates to another tab in my react application outside of the extension, and clicks the button, I want it to get the chrome.storage.local object I've stored.

Edit 2: It looks like it's saving the chrome.storage.local in the extension's console, but not on the main window/browser's console storage??

Comment: what is the value of `chrome`?

Comment: chrome shouldn't be anything. I'm trying to access Google Chrome's local storage.

Comment: what do you mean it shouldn't be anything? you're trying to access `chrome.storage.local` but the error indicates that `chrome.storage` is undefined.

Comment: When I console.log(chrome.storage), it returns undefined. When I console.log(chrome) it returns an object with: app: (...), csi: f(), loadTimes: f(), runtime: (...), getApp, setApp, getRuntime, setRuntime.   Edit: I'm trying to save information in a chrome extension. And then when the user navigates to another tab in my react application outside of the extension, and clicks the button, I want it to get the chrome.storage.local object I've stored. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok I think the issue is that it's saving the chrome.storage.local in the extension's console, and not the document/browser's console. How do I go about accessing the extension storage from a browser window?